# Diff. Geometry - prove that a straight line is the shortest length in Euclidean 3-space.

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors

Use the following scheme to prove that in ***E3*** a straight line is the shortest distance between two points. Let ***X : [a,b] → E3*** be a curve, and set ***x(a) = p***, ***x(b) = q***.

Hi everyone - I wanted to make sure I was on the right track. I believe I need to show that the distance between p and q is less than or equal to the arclength of some L - thereby showing that the shortest distance is always the straight line between them. Here's what I have so far:

***d(p,q) = q - p***

***X(t) = p + t(q - p) = p(1 - t) + tq*** (for t:[0,1])

***X'(t) = q - p***

***L = q - p***

Thereby proving that ***L = d(p,q)***.

But I feel like that was too easy. Did I calculate the arclength right? Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong.

First, $d(p,q) = |p-q|$; $p-q$ is a vector, $|p-q|$ is its length.

Second, you did not show how you got the arc length computation from the formula for $X'(t)$; and since you got a vector $p-q$, something is wrong.

Third, and most important, once you've correctly shown that the arc length of $X(t)$ equals $|p-q|$, you then have to show that *every other path* from $p$ to $q$ has arc length $\ge |p-q|$.

Comment: Okay, I understand the piece about the distance. It sounds like ***X(t)*** was defined correctly, and I found ***X'(t)*** okay. So ***L*** is the square root of the dot product of ***X'(t)***, so I should have ***L=(q^2+p^2)^1/2***. I am not seeing the relation to distance yet.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\gamma:I\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be a parametrized curve, suppose that $[a,b]\subset I$ and define $\gamma(a)=p, \gamma(b)=q$.

Then, for every vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^3$ with unit length we have

$$(q-p)\cdot v=(\gamma(b)-\gamma(a))\cdot v=\int_a^b\gamma'(t)\cdot v\,dt\leq\int_a^b|\gamma'(t)||v|\,dt=\int_a^b|\gamma'(t)|\,dt.$$

Thus if $v=\dfrac{q-p}{|q-p|}$ follows
$$|\gamma(b)-\gamma(a)|\leq\int_a^b|\gamma'(t)|\,dt$$

from which we can see that the shortest length curve from $\gamma(a)$ to $\gamma(b)$ is the line segment.